# Algorithm to view a larger container in a small screen

Tags: algorithm

I need a mathematical algorithm (or not) simple (or not, too).

It is as follows:
I have two numbers a and b, and need to find the smaller number closer to b, c.
Such that "a% c == 0"

If "a% b == 0", then c == b

Why is that?
My screen has size x pixels. And a container has pixels y such that y> x.

I want to calculate how much I have to scroll so that I can see my container on my screen without wasting space.
I want to necessarily roll to view.

I need to know just how much I need to roll, according to my screen and how often to view my entire container.

Answer (score 2):

This could you help? (Java code)

```
int a = 2000;
int b = 300;
int c = 0;

for (int i = b; i > 0; i--) {
     if ( (a % i) == 0) {
         c = i;
         break;
     }
}
```

The result will be in c.

Answer (score 0):

The problem asks, given `a` and `b`, find the largest `c` such that

- `c <= b`
- `c*k = a` for some `k`

The first constraint puts a lower bound on `k`, and maximizing `c` is equivalent to minimizing `k` given the second constraint.

The lower bound for `k` is given by

```
a = c*k <= b*k
```

and so `k >= a/b`. Therefore we just look for the smallest `k` that is a divisor of `a`, e.g.

```
if (b > a) return a; 
for (int k=a/b; k<=a; ++k)
    if (a % k == 0) {
        return a/k;
    }
}
```